# select2 | how to combine two select2 together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

The task is to determine which elements will be displayed in the second select after selecting an item from the first select.

For exmaple if I select first option from the first list, in the second list we must have only the elements of the first group.

HTML

```
<div>
  <select name="" id="select__brand">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="" id="select__model">
    <optgroup label="1">
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2">
      <option value="8">6</option>
      <option value="9">7</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3">
      <option value="10">6</option>
      <option value="11">7</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $('#select__brand').select2({
        placeholder: 'Mark',
  width: "100%"
    });
    $('#select__model').select2({
        placeholder: 'Model',
        width: "100%"
    });

var model;

    $('#select__brand').change(function () {
        model = $(this).val();
    });

$('#select__model').on('select2:open', function(e){
        $(".select2-results__option[aria-label]").hide();
        $(".select2-results__option[aria-label='" + model + "']").show();
});
```

Here you can see my tries. - http://jsfiddle.net/vahenm0z/10/

Comment: **[Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vahenm0z/22/)**

Comment: We are not compleating tasks here. 
What is you question? "Why list doesn't change?" It uses "show" for all options on open. So you need to use pause before hide them. 
@GuruprasadRao was so polite and fix you code. But please, ask questions not give tasks.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009382/javascript-make-select-2-use-url-set-by-outside-source/48011310#48011310